# Действия в программе в свернутом режиме

Tags: c#

У меня появилась такая проблема:

Есть программа (игра), там нужно нажимать клавиши клавиатуры. Сами нажатия я уже сделал, но!

Можно ли направлять действия моей программы (нажатия клавиш, клики мыши) в свернутую, не выделенную игру?

Comment: думаю, что это будет полезно для ознакомления: [listen for a key when the application is not focused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065906/5275890) Если будут пожелания, могу перевести на русский и опубликовать ответом. И не менее полезное: [Background applications listening for keyboard activity](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9351/Background-applications-listening-for-keyboard-act)

Comment: Вроде, через хуки можно такое сделать.